# Does Scriptella read all the records into memory before writing to a CSV file

Tags: scriptella

Does Scriptella (1.0 release) reads all the records into the memory before it starts writing to a CSV file if we are using a CSVDriver. If I read 10 million records from a DB then it reads all these 10 million records before it starts writing to a file or whether it reads in a batched mode ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Scriptella avoids keeping data in memory whenever possible.

In a basic non-optimized case it reads records one by one and send them to another data-source. In addition to that, depending on a driver and/or additional settings, certain optimizations can be added. [Batching](http://scriptella.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/support-for-jdbc-batching-and-query-fetch-has-been-added/) can be enabled so that records are fetches and sent in batches. Depending on databases and available memory batches can be from 100 to 10000(or more) records. In this case only one batch is kept in memory. Please note that batching is available in Scriptella 1.1.